# Wrong JDK Path set in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8, sdk

I am using `Android Studio 3.0` to make my android app. But due to the layout not rendering properly I had to reinstall the Android studio. But however I did not delete the original Android Studio but instead change the name of the original folder`(android studio)` to `(android studio 1)`.

But somehow the new Android Studio download could not be used then I simply deleted the new Android Studio and changed back the name of the old to the same i.e. `android studio`.

But when I opened it was not able to locate the `JDK` and on pressing `alt+enter` on the error I had an option to set the JDK. There were four option one is the `java ...` version and the other three were `api 23`, `api 24`, and `api 25`.

I chose the `java ...` and then the `Context` class was not found.

Can anyone help me to achieve back the original state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top left `File>Project structure` a window will pop up. Go to `SDK Location` then look for `Use embedded JDK`. [image]

Comment: Really Thank You for the help. You saved me.

Comment: Any idea on how to rectify the Layout preview?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get what you are asking?!

Comment: My Android Studio the previewer of the XML layout is not working fine. I mean the layout editor in Android Studio is not showing the preview of the XML code properly. The preview of the layout is empty.

Comment: that is another question, please create a new question and on `StackOverflow` and I'll try to answer it there

Comment: OK. Will create in some time and will update you in soon. Anyway thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I have posted a new Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440051/android-studio-3-0-layout-editor-previewer can you please try and help with this also. Sorry it took some time due to Stack Overflows limit on posting question.

Comment: As of Android Studio 4, the checkbox is gone for `Use Embedded JDK`. Now it is an option in the dropdown under `JDK Location`.