# Android Studio 3.0 Layout Editor/Previewer

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio 3.0 to make an Android App.

But the issue I am facing is that the Layout editor/previewer is not working properly. It is sometimes not showing anything and at times it is showing a grey box with all the navigation buttons.

These are the screenshots

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

I am using the `buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'` and the support libraries version is `23.0.1`

Any help would be really helpful.

**EDIT: This is my XML Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="33dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     </LinearLayout>

     </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The preview may be empty or in error if the project has not yet build. But if already build then a quick fix is rebuilding or cleaning the project...

Comment: ^ Try the above, if that doesn't work then go to `File > invalidate cache/restart`

Comment: @Xenolion Thanks for the answer. I have tried rebuilding, Cleaning, Invalidating cache and restarting but none of the solution actually worked. Any idea?

Comment: @MohammedAlSafwan Tried that also but did not work. Any other solution which I can try?

Comment: Does your layout have views???

Comment: if you look at the bottom, there is `Design` and `Text`. Press on `Text` and post the XML code

Comment: @Xenolion Yes it has. In fact when I build the apk and tested it on a real device and it works fine. I even tried setting background color to the layout but then even that did not show up.

Comment: @MohammedAlSafwan OK. Updating soon.

Comment: If the problem persist for too long, you may need to adjust memory given to Android Studio by your computer etc

Comment: @MohammedAlSafwan  I have added my XML Layout. Please check.

Comment: @Xenolion I have added my XML Layout. Please check. Can you guide on how to do that.

Comment: do you have any error or side messages showing up?

Comment: @MohammedAlSafwan No. There are no error showing up. My previous Android Studio 2.0 use to work perfectly but Android Studio 3.0 is giving me issues. Sometime it shows up half, sometime the layout is not only shown.

Comment: @MohammedAlSafwan I have read other Stack Overflow posts there are many issues which describe a similar problem. Is it something to do with the Android Studio 3.0 or some of its setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a couple of problem with structuring your UI. Here is a fix, also make sure that the `@drawable/logo` file is at the `drawable folder`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/logo"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/logo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="33sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="207dp"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="33sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />
```

Comment: Thanks once again. Just for info what were the errors in the layout that was written by me, I myself still cannot identify them. And also is it compulsory to use Constrain Layout?

Comment: They weren't errors, but more of logical structure problems. you had a textview that had `wrap_content` for it is width, but had no content, so it wasn't showing up. you also had nested views that had no reason to be there, so I fixed that for you too.

Comment: Thanks. Will approach you if I have any issues in future :).